# Java: How do I remove parameter from querystring

Tags: java, query-string

I want to remove some querystring attribute from my url, I tried some regex but didn't get the exact solution for this. Please help me to out of it.
eg:

```
String qString = "category=Popular&code=14290115";
qString = qString .replaceAll("(?<=[?&;])code=.*?($|[&;])",""); 
output: category=Popular&
```

the above regex is removing the attribute but not removing `&` symbol. So please suggest me for this.

Comment: no... I just want to remove only `case` parameter. I want this: `http://www.domain.com?id=1&start=2&end=5`

Comment: what is the problem? It works fine. [See Demo here](http://ideone.com/tBjgBT)

Comment: Why don't you just split into query elements, build a list from the array without the element you want and reconstruct the query string?

Comment: there is a problem only when case is the last parameter. So maybe, after the replacement, you can test if qString ends with '&' and remove it.

Comment: Oh Sorry... I edited my question. I am using this  `id=1&case=edit&start=2&end=5` as `query string`

Comment: Your regex works fine (i've tested it). If it still doesn't work I'd recommed the _KISS_ principle _(Keep It Simple, Stupid)_. Use [`String#substring` or `String$split`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/)

Comment: Yes you are right... but in some cases it failes and added the extra `&` symobol... [check this](http://ideone.com/vYKlA1) or try `String qString = category=Popular&code=14290115;`

Comment: If I tried to remove the last one then it fails... have you got the issue @ambigram_maker ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a regex for this. It's an utter nightmare because any character could be percent-encoded, e.g. `?foo=bar` is exactly the same as `?%66oo=%62ar`. Parse the URL, then the query string, then rebuild it. Take a look at URIBuilder and URLEncodedUtils out of the Apache Commons HTTP Client.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your suggestion @David, I need to try and check.

Comment: I am using `URIBuilder` and its really helpful. Thanks @David